# Converting LPBYTE to char*

Tags: c++, c

After 2 hours of google on "Convert LPBYTE to char*" i only found result that relates with **"RegQueryValueExW"**

No one use "LPBYTE" other than "RegQueryValueExW" function.

My question arise with unicode and ASCII conversion if i use RegQueryValueEx that will give me all ASCII values correct but as multinational point view this will not helping me.

Now,

I have following code ,

```
char* GetStringRegKey(HKEY hKey, LPCWSTR strValueName, char* strValue, char* strDefaultValue)
{
    strValue = strDefaultValue;
    char szBuffer[512];
    DWORD dwBufferSize = sizeof(szBuffer);
    ULONG nError;
    LPCWSTR TempPassingString;
    char* hostName;
    nError = RegQueryValueExW(hKey, strValueName, 0, NULL, (LPBYTE)szBuffer, &dwBufferSize);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == nError)
    {
        strValue = szBuffer;
    }
    USES_CONVERSION;
    return strValue;
}
```

This will show me **szBuffer** array like,
[image]

Which is correct value.( note "C" aftet pointer value).
But when i assign it to another character array **strValue** then only "C" is display as value of strValue;

As shown below.

[image]

This may be foolish question but i dont understand where i am going wrong.
Please suggest any help, block of code or hint that will convert my whole szBuffer to strValue.

Comment: You see that conveniently skipped fourth parameter you're passing NULL for in your [`RegQueryValueExW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911(v=vs.85).aspx) invoke? That would be the *type*, and I would advise some time investigating what values it returns, and what data format you can expect for your resultant data. Then, I would investigate the narrow-version of the same function, `RegQueryValueExA()`. Your current return string is likely type `REG_SZ` and because you're using the wide-char version of the API, the string is Unicode.

Comment: @WhozCraig parameter mismatch is not there because mmy function is successfully execute and return me 0 as error status which is valid even if i pass valid parameter of registry type bibary it will not work.

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade I didn't say it was a mismatch. I said you're using the wide-char version of `RegQueryValueEx`, which will return **Unicode** values for items of type REG_SZ, REG_MULTI_SZ, etc. Its [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911(v=vs.85).aspx). The function always requires a LPBYTE parameter, but the *data* returned for the string types will be Unicode. If you want narrow representation you have to either use RegQueryValueExA or convert to something like CP_UTF8 using `WideCharToMultiByte()` after the fetch.

Comment: @WhozCraig are you saying that, first take value as LPBYTE and then convert it into CP_UTF8

Comment: @Something like that, yes. There are literally tens-of-*thousands* of examples of how to use RegQueryValueEx on the web, hundreds here on SO. Take a bit of time and see how it is used, and above all, *read the documentation*. It really will answer just about any question you have.

Comment: You really should try to understand the difference between `RegQueryValueExW()`and `RegQueryValueExA()` in particular and the difference of functions suffixed `A` and `W` in general!

Comment: @WhozCraig got it but it same how do convert LPBYTE to CP_UTF8 and then to char*

Comment: @alk i understand the difference between RegQueryValueExW()and RegQueryValueExA()  then what?? are you suggesting me to use RegQueryValueExA() or anything else??

Comment: If you want to have the reg-entry as ANSI (single character) representation: yes, use `RegQueryValueExA()`. If you want the multi-character representation I do not understad why you want to use `char` then. Use `wchar_t` and the `wcs*()`family of "string" functions, like `wcscpy()` as replacement to `strcpy()`. (see also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kk6xf663.aspx)

Comment: @alk Tell me one thing ASCII cannot contain UNICODE charecter is UNICODE contain ASCII charecters??

Comment: The reg-value you show in your example is the `wchar_t` representation of the reg-value placed in a `BYTE` array, where `BYTE` most certainly is the same as `char`. An `A` is represented in ANSI as value `65` and in UNICODE as `65 0`. Learn about the differences between `char`, `wchar_t`, ANSI, UNICODE, MULTIBYTE, UTF8, UTF16, UTF32 ... then come back! However then you won't have the need to ask about it here anymore ... ;-)

Comment: right and perfect suggestion :-) cheers..